# Highly correlated residuals from auto.arima

Tags: r, time-series, arima, modeling, residuals

I am using `auto.arima` for a simple sine time series where `freq = 3`. The series is plotted as follows:

[image: Time series]

I use the following code for model fitting:

```
data = ts(x,frequency=3,start = 1)
model = auto.arima(data,stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE)
plot(data$residuals,type='l')
```

When I check the residuals of the fitted model, they are highly correlated like a sine time series (the p-value of the Ljung-Box test is zero). The following plot depicts the residuals:

[image]

Can anybody help me to find out the reason of bad fitted model and not having random residuals?

Comment: Could you edit the post to include the output of `auto.arima`?

Comment: Could you also include a link to the data?